# How can I get the required sum from this array

Tags: php

This is the code I currently have:

```
$required = 1.3;
$stacks = 0;
$remaining = $required;
$whichtakes = [];
$array_result = ['0.6', '0.5', '0.8', '0.7'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($array_result); $i++) {
    if($array_result[$i] <= $required  && $stacks + $array_result[$i]  <= $required) {
        $stacks += $array_result[$i];
        echo $remaining -= $array_result[$i];
        $whichtakes[] = $array_result[$i];
    }
}
print_r($whichtakes);
```

Output is

```
Array (
    [0] => 0.6
    [1] => 0.5
)
```

This is fetching just 0.6 and 0.5 (first two values) and gives a remaining value (the sum is 1.1, so 0.2 is remaining). But the input has 2 values whose sum matches with my `$required` value: 0.8 and 0.7.

How can I improve my code so that it will find those values? If there is no exact match possible, I would like to get a series of values whose sum comes as close as possible, minimising the remaining value.

Comment: Your question is unclear (at least to me). What is the desired result?

Comment: 0.8 + 0.7 == 1.5 , why are you saying that these values match to exact your `$required` == 1.3 ?

Comment: Your title mentions "closest pairs", but there is nothing in your code or description that has anything to do with finding closest pairs. NB: You should really indent your code properly.

Comment: You never reset the values of `$stacks` and `$remaining` within the loops. Your algorithm will not work.

Comment: sorry for unclear

Comment: sorry for unclear question  
$array_result = ['0.6', '0.5', '0.8', '0.7','1.1']; 
my algorithm  will get  0.6 and 0.5 not 1.1 , and if array like this 

$array_result = ['0.6', '0.4', '0.8', '0.7','0.6','0.5'];

my algorithm will get 0.6 and 0.4 and give me 0.1 renaming. it will not pick 0.6 and 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more explanation in comments, it turns out you want to find an algorithm for this input/output:

Input:

- a total amount, and
- an array with amounts

Output:

- the "closest subset": a selection of amounts from the input array  (not necessarily a pair) that has the largest sum that is not greater than the given total amount.
- the difference between the sum of that subset and the given total amount

You can achieve that as follows:

Generate all combinations, keyed by the sums (or remainders) they generate, but stop adding elements when their sums becomes too large. This can be done with simple iteration over the elements and updating a hash, keyed by the sums (or remainders) that are found by adding the value to previously found sums.

Here is how that looks:

```
// Input
$required = 1.3;
$array_result = [0.6, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7];

// Algorithm
$remainings = [(string)$required => []]; // Keyed by remaining value; gives array elements that have that remainder

foreach($array_result as $i => $val) {
    foreach($remainings as $remaining => $whichtakes) {
        if ($remaining >= $val) $remainings[(string)($remaining-$val)] = array_merge($whichtakes, [$val]);
    }
}
$remaining = min(array_keys($remainings));
$whichtakes = $remainings[(string)$remaining];

// Output
print_r($whichtakes);   // [0.6, 0.7]
print_r($remaining);    // 0
```

Comment: hi sir, its working perfect, but there is little change  , your Algorithm is getting pairs but i want array which match my result array, just need this little change. if $required = 1.3 change to $required = 1.8 now it should give me array 0.6,0.5,0.7 and if $required = 1.9 now it should give me array 0.6,0.5,0.7  and 0.1 remaining

Comment: sif if $required = 0.5; and $array_result = [1]; than its gives me in renaming 0.5 and nothing in $whichtakes , i thinks its have to give me $whichtakes = 0.5 and renaming 0.5, the condition in if ($remaining >= $val) is not true is we need here a else statement ?? please guide

Comment: I thought your initial question was that `$whichtakes` should take values ***from the array***, so it could never be 0.5 in your example: the `$array_result` only has value 1.

Comment: yes values from the array but it can be one result in array, i am testing with one result which get from array

Comment: else if($remaining <= $val){
                                        
                                        $new = $val - $remaining;
                                        $remainings[(string)($val - $remaining)] = array_merge($whichtakes, [$new]);
                                        
                                    }
is this work ? please guide

Comment: I don't understand. You say 'yes values from the array' but 0.5 is not in your array, so it should not appear in `whichtakes`.

Comment: ok, please see this link. now i am trying this, i know my question req is meet with your answer. thanks for that but when we go for decimal, it have some problems just link below link,i request you to please check the link 
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9u95-x1nh

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you try to achieve. May I suggest that you create a new question where you clearly explain what you want to achieve? You can then post the link to that new question here, and I will have look at it if no-one else does.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm will find all pairs that adds up to the `$required` value:

```
$required = 1.3;
$array_result = ['0.6', '0.5', '0.8', '0.7'];

$answers = [];
foreach ($array_result as $value) {

    $remaining = $required - $value;
    if (in_array((string)$remaining, $array_result)) {
        $new_answer = ($value <= $remaining ? [$value, $remaining] : [$remaining, $value]);
        $answers[] = $new_answer;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_unique($answers, SORT_REGULAR));
echo '</pre>';
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.6
            [1] => 0.7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.5
            [1] => 0.8
        )

)
```